# QLabel doesnot display image when run from QtCreator

Tags: image, qt, qlabel

When i run the program with QtCreator 2.7.0 a blank application window appears. When i run the executable in the release folder it works. What can be the problem?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QLabel topLevelLabel;
QPixmap pixmap("gem.jpg");
topLevelLabel.setPixmap(pixmap);
topLevelLabel.setMask(pixmap.mask());
topLevelLabel.show();
return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is in relative path. Try to use absolute, or, better - add image to resources.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your pixmap is failed to load because image file cannot be found. You should check it using `pixmap.isNull()` before using it.

It's better to place the image file into Qt resources file, so it will be included in the executable file.

If you still want to load file that is saved in the same directory as the executable, note that `"gem.jpg"` is relative path to the working directory. You need to find your executable location using `QApplication::arguments().at(0)` and construct the absolute path of the image. Note however that Qt Creator usually generates executable in a temporary build directory, so you need to copy your image file into it.

Well, like I said, it's better to place the image file into Qt resources file.